# Want to write a function that takes a csv file as an argument

Tags: r, function, csv

I am trying to write a function that would take a csv file as an argument.

What I am trying to do is as follows:

```
myCSVfunction <- function(.csv){
  headVal<-head(.csv)
  string("The head of the dataset is: %d",headVal)
```

In completion of the function making, I want it to do do the following:

```
>myCSVfunction(C:/Path/file.csv)
>The head value of the dataset is:
...("Head" of the data here)...
```

Please note that I tried doing a lot of Googling and tried some random trials myself before posting.

Thank you.

Comment: Here's a tutorial you can check out in addition to the answer below- http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/input.html#read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read the csv in R, or else it doesn't know what it's looking at, also you should probably pass the file into the function as a string.

```
myCSVfunction <- function(.csv) {
    csv <- read.csv(.csv)
    headValue <- head(csv)
    print("The head of the dataset is:")
    return(headValue) # or print(headValue) if you prefer
}
```

For instance:

```
write.csv(mtcars, "mtcars.csv", row.names = FALSE)
myCSVfunction("mtcars.csv")
#[1] "The head of the dataset is:"
#mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: You are saying me read the file but you are using write.csv; can't I use read.csv?

Comment: Sorry, I used `write.csv()` so that I could arbitrarily create a csv file to test `myCSVfunction`. If you look at how `myCSVfunction` is defined, it takes the argument and calls `read.csv`

Comment: So, if I do read.csv(tips, "C:/path/tips.csv", row.named = FALSE) and the do myCSVfunction("tips.csv"), will it work?

Comment: It is working. Thanks a lot. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I think it's best if you look at the help docs for these functions. I don't think they do what you think they do. `?write.csv` and `?read.csv`